# group objects under Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word, grouping, shortcut

we group frequently objects under WOrd 2013. Usually, we use mouse or shortcut (Alt key + j, y, ù, g ,r for french version).
I would like to group all the selected objetcs with a shortcut (Ctrl+G) or by a VBA macro with this shortcut

Currently i found a code to group the two first elements by index

```
Sub Grouper()
'ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Name, ActiveDocument.Shapes(2).Name)).Select
'Selection.ShapeRange.Group
End Sub
```

But of course if i have 10 objects to group or if i want to groupe the items 7 to 9, it does not work
So i search a way to define an array with the selected objetcs in VBA or any other method to achieve this aim.

Comment: _Ctrl + G_ is working here to group selected objects. I don't see any point in making the process more complicated.

Comment: The shortcut works BUT with this code snippet, only two elements are grouped. If there are more element it does not work

Comment: Why are you using the code snippet? The program already groups selected objects, why duplicate that function with VBA?